# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de palabras claves en un EditText?

Tags: android, edittext, pseudocódigo

gracias de antemano por tener el tiempo para ayudarme.

Estoy realizando algo parecido a un editor de pseudocódigo, y necesito cambiar el color de las palabras reservadas de tales como *Leer*, *Escribir*, *Si*, etc.

Gracias a una librería, me ahorro el trabajo de la busqueda y cambio del color de las palabras, ya que a esta librería yo le envío el texto, texto a buscar y el color, y me devuelve todo en código html, pudiendo con ello cambiar el color en un EditText gracias al evento `Html.fromHtml`.

Mi problema se genera a la hora de encontrar un evento que me permita cambiar el color del texto al EditText, ya eh probado con el evento `onTextChanged` instanciando un `TextWatcher`y asignándolo al EditText, pero esto me genera un bucle infinito, el cual eh intentado controlar con una variable booleana, pero me da errores al escribir, ya que se duplican las palabras entre otras cosas.

Esto es lo que he echo hasta ahora:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher= new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                textoAntes=s.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             if(!isChange)
            {
                isChange=true;
                textCode.setText(Html.fromHtml(palabrasReservadas.getTextReservado(s.toString())));
            }
            isChange=false;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            textCode.setSelection(s.length());

        }
    };

    this.textCode.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba sin usar el textwatcher. Con el onTextChanged solo tienes que capturar el valor una unica vez, analizar si figura en la libreria y en caso afirmativo cambiarle el color. El onTextChanged ocuparia el lugar del textwatcher, creo que por eso te realiza el bucle infinito. Saludos.

Comment: lo intente pero sigue generando el bucle